# Jmeter wont read csv file with line feed properly

Tags: jmeter

I have a thread which writes data to a csv file and data looks like this in that file, as you see below each data is separated by a `,` then line feed.

```
ApiKey
20a145260241463194bf84f43952da9c:dut8ghdt+iQrsmYEgKzHzF1It79aWRIjb/d1wM8U3WE=,
93,
d0e29bb7-476d-4a52-9527-e5d9bb0ac34a
```

---

In another thread I am trying to read the data so I have done the following. Added a "CSV Data Set Config"  with correct filename variables X,Y,Z and my Delimiter I have tried all these A=,n or B=n or C=n,  I am not able to get Y and Z properly.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your CSV format is invalid to what you want to achieve. Fix writing thread so that it doesn't add newlines between fields of the same entry. Newlines are only for delimiting separate entries.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization of data between thread groups using CSV files is not the best idea as you will have to implement a form or [read/write lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) to ensure that only one thread is writing data to the CSV file at a time and that will cause throughput degradation.

So I would recommend going for one of the following solutions:

1. Use [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function to convert the data from JMeter Variables into JMeter Properties. JMeter Properties are global for the whole JVM therefore they can be accessed from another Thread Group(s). See [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) article for more information.
2. Use [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin which implements [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) queue so you can block threads in 2nd thread group unless data from 1st thread group is available. You can install Inter-Thread Communication Plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Both approaches are **in-memory** therefore you will not need to store data in interim files.